# Stopping 'with' attribute recursion in Laravel Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Assume two Eloquent models in Laravel - `user` and `location`.

User:

```
class User extends Model
{    
    /**
     * Relations that should be automatically loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $with = [
        'locations'
    ];

    /**
     * Returns relation to the locations table.
     */
    public function locations() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Location');
    }
}
```

Location:

```
class Location extends Model
{    
    /**
     * Relations that should be automatically loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $with = [
        'users'
    ];

    /**
     * Returns relation to the users table.
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

As you can see, they both have the public attribute `with` - because as these models are driving an API, I want the users to *always* be returned with their location, and locations to *always* be returned with a list of their users.

However, as I thought might happen, this has led to the request timing out due to (I think) recursion. In other words, the location loads its users, and they load their locations, which then load their users, and so on.

Is there any way in Laravel to force it *not* to recurse into the same model that is doing the 'initial loading'?

I should mention that `user` also has another relation, `profile`, that I want to load in every query. So if, for example, there's a way to simply kill `with` eager-loading after a certain 'depth', that won't do it.

EDIT: I *am* aware that I can use `User::with('location')->find();` to eager-load the relations, however this solution requires me to use that extra code *everywhere* I am retrieving users. I am looking for a solution that will let me *always* eager-load the relationships automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no - there is no way to prevent recursion when automatically eager-loading a relation that automatically eager-loads the relation back your original object. You just need to decide which 'direction' you'd prefer to automatically eager load, and manually eager load whenever you need the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a infinite loop of loading for example you called a `User` now it is loading  `Location` but when `Location` loaded then it again called `User` it has been loaded and the same loading process is going on so it makes a loop which is not even breaking. that why it is give a error

you can do like this

```
User::with('location')->find(..) // or get or any
```

Comment: I _do_ understand why it's happening, as I said in the question. I asked how to stop it happening. Just to clarify: I do know I can load the relations manually every time, however I would _much_ prefer to have the relations eager-load automatically, without me needing to specify.

Comment: it is the time to ask to  **Taylor Otwell** about this

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this problem, just put other model in belongsTo method.

1. Create new empty JustLocation model extends Location model.
2. Set `protected $with = [];` in JustLocation model
3. Change `return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Location');` to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\JustLocation');` in the User model.

Comment: come on dude... that is really not a good idea.